# Can't click a subutton in a pop-up

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem with selenium:

I'm not able to click a button that is included in a pop-up originated by the first button that I click.

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

    # Webdriver
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\zlell\\PycharmProjects\\PyroLello\\Userbot\\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get("https://www.eventbrite.com/e/120621788015")

    # This button originates a pop-up
    python_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="eventbrite-widget-modal-trigger-120621788015"]')

    # Click
    python_button.click()

    # The pop-up with the new button appears

    # Try to find the button included in the pop-up - Doesn't work
    python_button_2 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button.eds-btn.eds-btn--button.eds-btn--fill")

    # Click - Doesn't Work
    python_button_2.click()
```

The error:

> ```
> // TRACEBACK:
> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button.eds-btn.eds-btn--butt
> on.eds-btn--fill"}
>  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:\Users\zlell\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-pack
> ages\Python38\site-packages\pyrogram\dispatcher.py", line 208, in handler_worker
>    await handler.callback(self.client, *args)
>  File "C:\users\zlell\PycharmProjects\PyroLello\Userbot\pyro.py", line 318, in test
>    python_button_2 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button.eds-btn.eds-btn--button.eds-btn--fill")
>  File "C:\Users\zlell\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-pack
> ages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 598, in find_element_by_css_selector
>    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
>  File "C:\Users\zlell\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-pack
> ages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
>    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
>  File "C:\Users\zlell\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-pack
> ages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
>    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>  File "C:\Users\zlell\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-pack
> ages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
>    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":"button.eds-btn.eds-btn--button.eds-btn--fill"}
>  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)
> ```

Second Button - Included in the pop-up:

[image: Second Button - Included in the pop-up]

Comment: you are using the wrong selector i think. are you sure the css selector should be like button.class1.class2.class3 ?

Comment: I've already tried using: - xPath, - Class, - CSS Selector

Comment: Use a webdriver wait in between the clicks. As well as go into the iframe.

Comment: Can you please gimme an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a wait after page load. Grab the iframe and switch to it.

```
iframe = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)
python_button_2 =WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.eds-btn.eds-btn--button.eds-btn--fill")))
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```